# Google Ads API | Intellij | java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, google-ads-api

I tried to clone the [Google Ads GitHub library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/releases) (adwords-axis-jars-and-examples) but when I try to run the GetCampaigns.java file I get this error:
[build output in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbKj8.png)

So I tried to change the compiler settings that people have recommended, still no luck.
[Compiler settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAUwL.png)

I downloaded the adwords-axis-jars-and-examples, but do I need to download the adwords-axis-maven-and-examples for this [GitHub library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/releases)?

If you can help me with this I will Venmo or Cash App you $. I'm just learning how to program so forgive me in advance.

Comment: What JDK version/build/vendor do you use? Does it help if you switch to a more recent one?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm using Oracle OpenJDK 16.0.1

Comment: Does it fail with JDK 8 as well?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample project to reproduce and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) attached.